# Variable functions definitions inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Does defining functions inside a loop affect performance?

Like

```
var doSomething = function(element){
      $(element).whatever();
    };

return this.each(function(){
  doSomething(this);
})
```

vs

```
return this.each(function(){

  var element = this,
      doSomething = function(){
        element.whatever();
      };


  doSomething(); 
  ...
})
```

In 2nd version the function gets defined like 324532453245 times, depending on how many elements are being iterated, right?

Comment: Right. I'd use the first version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you're defining a defining the functions 80 bajillion times or so in both versions.  For high volumes of iteration, you should get some performance benefit from defining it like [this](http://api.jquery.com/each/#example-2).

```
var doSomething = function(index, element){
      $(element).whatever();
    };

return this.each(doSomething);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend using http://jsperf.com/ to test questions like this.

All we will be able to give you is our best educated guess based on our personal experience which will vary widely.

EDIT: Also what doSomething is doing is hugely important in answering this question as well.

I myself have been surprised before by doing testing myself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

well, the scope of `element` and thus the `doSomething` is just within the current loop iteration, so if everything is implemented correctly, ie the garbage collector is optimized, it should handle it fine. Of course, you're much better off using the first version.